# Getting main folder

Tags: php

To this day i'm using that piece of code to locate public_html to count the folders to go back in order to import files:

```
$config_path = array_reverse(explode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , getcwd()));
$co = 0;
foreach($config_path as $val){
    if($val == "public_html")
        break;
    $co += 1;
}
$config_path = '';

if($co != 0){
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $co ; $i++){
        $config_path .= '../';
    }
}
```

and then i'm using it like that:

```
require_once ($config_path.'core/db-class.php');
```

That piece of code serve me pretty good , though I feel like its limiting me because when I use WAMP I need to have public_html folder and such

I'm looking for a php function something like - `getMainRoot()`

So I can do something like

```
require_once (getMainRoot().'core/db-class.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` php variable.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the website must not be placed at the servers document root at all. More helpful are normally the `__DIR__` constant as it allows to operate relative the the current files which's location is normally known relative to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

One can always use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but that does not work running the *internal web server* or from the *command line*.

If your application has a *single entry point* like `index.php` you can make a define there:

```
define( 'ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ );
```

and use that from there on.

Comment: my main folder is `"Main"` , i want to run that line from `"Main/Core/Config.php"` so i cant execute it as `define ( 'ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ );` so i can do something like `define ( 'ROOT_PATH', 'Main' );` , how can i do that?

Comment: I do it like this : `require_once ROOT_PATH . '/Main/Core/Config.php'` note: your application needs a single entry point like index.php